# Unit Test - Using MockMvc to test the controller with @RequestHeader with HashMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I have a controller that has the following structure:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/validate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Jwt> IsValid(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> header) throws Exception {
    if(header.contains("key") && header.contains("secret") {
        process(header.get("key"), header.get("secret"));
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test for this controller using MockMvc:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthenticatorServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void CorrectKeyValidation throws Exception {
        String key = "correct-key";
        String secret = "correct-secret";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", key);
        map.put("secret", secret);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/validate")
                .header() // <- doesn't accept Map here.
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        ...
        ... 
    }  
}
```

Since the `header` method for `MockMvcRequestBuilders` only accepts string, Im not really sure how to use MockMvc to test my controller which has `Map<String, String>` as a `@RequestHeader`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `@RequestHeader Map<String, String> header` means it will inject all the headers in that map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate a bit on that? I tried sending with mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/validate")
                .header("key", key)
                .header("secret", secret)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
but couldn't really get it working, since it is throwing `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException`. Maybe I'm missing something here..

Comment: By the way: Don't do that. Use `@RequestHeader("key")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another method like below (.headers(*)), you can use that , just verified.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", key);
        map.put("secret", secret);
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setAll(map);
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/scheduler/enable")
                .headers(httpHeaders)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(this.getRequstAsJSON()))
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried, but I am still getting the following error:
`Handler: Type = com.louprogramming.controller.AuthController            Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.louprogramming.domain.Jwt> com.louprogramming.controller.AuthController.IsValid(com.louprogramming.domain.UserRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws java.lang.Exception. Resolved Exception:              Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException.`

Do you have any insights on why this is happening?

Comment: Is your API in working condition , means Can you hit your API using Postman or something , using all the headers that you are passing through the test case ?

Comment: Thank you! Just got it working by adding in .content.

Comment: I see one issue with your code, I am not sure why you did it but , @RequestHeader is meant for 1 key/value at a time , for more , you need to repeat it . I believe that could be possible issue . https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers

Comment: The reason why I chose Map<String, String> is because the users might send `key & secret` or `client_id` based on the situation. I tried having it separated out into 3 different @RequestHeaders but when one was missing, it was throwing exceptions. Would it be possible to have it missing a value based on the situation?

Comment: @AjeetMaurya `@RequestHeader` will also work with a map, that is even a documented and supported case. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestheader. Please don't spread information that isn't true.